# Bing Maps Multiple Pushin Infoboxes

Tags: bing-maps

I have a map where I have multiple pushpins, and would like the infobox to support HTML content.  I'm using the native infobox class, and while I have used a custom infobox, as many have suggested, I'd like to figure this one out.

The code is at: http://brickenandassociates.com/bm.php

Its not compressed or encoded, so you can just view the source.

at line 84, the options for the Infobox are set.  In the description, I've tried setting a var , but am missing the syntax somewhere.  Something like this :

var ibDescription = document.getElementById('ibDescription');
ibDescription.innerHTML = e.target.description;

Any guidance would be most appreciated !

Comment: I traveled a different route and used a custom infobox.  It just needed to get done.  Here are the results: 

http://brickenandassociates.com/pin_test3.php

Here's how I found the center and then centered the box starting at line 682:

// divide width and heighth
viewportwidth = viewportwidth /2;
viewportheight = viewportheight /2;

infoBox.style.top = (viewportheight - 320) + "px";
infoBox.style.left = (viewportwidth - 225) + "px";
infoBox.style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById('myMap').appendChild(infoBox);
}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've figured this out already:

```
pinInfobox.setOptions({title: e.target.Title, description: e.target.Description, visible:true, offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0,25)});

pinInfobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
```

One thing I noted was that you are only using one InfoBox. I use one info box per pushpin, so I set the infobox detail at the time it is created and then only have to hide or show it.